# How to use YUI Compressor PHP port

Tags: php, compression, yui

I'm having trouble getting https://github.com/gpbmike/PHP-YUI-Compressor to work:

In my /js directory I have:

1. yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
2. yui.php
3. jquery.js
4. jsall.php
5. "temp" folder set to 777

in jsall.php:

```
<?php 
// INCLUDE COMPRESSOR CLASS
include('yui.php');

// INVOKE CLASS
$yui = new YUICompressor('yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar', 'temp', $options);

// ADD FILES
$yui->addFile('jquery.js');

// COMPRESS
$code = $yui->compress();
?>
```

Echoing $code gives me the following:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   java.lang.VMClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.10) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.10) at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.10) at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.10) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.10) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.10) at
>   gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.10)

What am I doing wrong here?